# orthogonal complement of an empty subset

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a linear algebra textbook and below is the definition of orthogonal complement:

[image]

My question is, if U is an empty subset, does it make sense to talk about its orthogonal complement? Is the orthogonal complement of an empty subset the whole space W because of vacuous truth?

Comment: The answer to your last sentence is: yes. Note that this is consistent with the theorem $A^\bot=({\rm span}(A))^\bot,$ since ${\rm span}(\varnothing)=\{0\}$ and $\{0\}^\bot=W.$

Comment: Thank you! There was not such a theorem in my book but it makes a lot of sense (also might be the reason why we often talk about the orthogonal complement of subspaces).